# BokehJS FreehandDrawTool does not plot line when dragging mouse in canvas

Tags: javascript, bokeh, bokehjs

In BokehJS 2.4.2 the [FreehandDrawTool documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#freehanddrawtool) is showing in the toolbar, but no line is drawn when dragging the mouse in the canvas.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the problem. This example is so minimalistic it is hard to figure out what could possibly be wrong.

```js
let plot = Bokeh.Plotting.figure({
    tools: ['freehand_draw'],
    x_range: [0, 100],
    y_range: [0, 100],
});
```

Output of the minimal code to reproduce the problem

[image: Output of the minimal code to reproduce the problem]

Example from the [FreehandDrawTool documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#freehanddrawtool)

[image: Example from the FreehandDrawTool documentation]

What could prevent the line to be drawn when dragging the mouse in the canvas?

The goal is to have a working FreehandDrawTool.

**UPDATE 1**

Modified example according to Python example from @mosc9575 as follows and it works! The tool should be inactive by default, it will not work when the tool is active by default. When the FreehandDrawTool is active by default you need de deactivate and activate the tool again for it to work.

```js
let source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
    data : {
        xs: [[0,50,100]],
        ys: [[0,50,0]],
    },
});

let r = plot.multi_line({
    'xs': { field: 'xs' },
    'ys': { field: 'ys' },
    source: source,
});

let freehand_draw = new Bokeh.FreehandDrawTool({
    active: false,
    empty_value: 1,
    renderers: [r],
});

plot.add_tools(freehand_draw);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the language information to your post, to make clear if you are looking for a python or js solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neew to create a renderer to make your example work. Without this renderer the draw tool has no option to add this values.

**Python example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import FreehandDrawTool, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

plot = figure(
    x_range =  [0, 100],
    y_range =  [0, 100],
    width=400,
    height=400,
    tools = ""
)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(xs=[[0,0]], ys=[[0,0]]))

r = plot.multi_line('xs', 'ys', source=source)
tool = FreehandDrawTool(renderers=[r], empty_value=1)
plot.add_tools(tool)
show(plot)
```

It looks like your are doing this in JS and not in python, therefore this copy will not work as copy'n'paste, but it ilustrates the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mosc9575. I modified the code to your Python example and the default line is plotted. However, still no additional lines are plotted when dragging the mouse.